# How to stop the workflow myself for SPO with Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, approval-process, approval

I am creating an approval workflow for SPO with Power Automate.

I can send an approve or reject email to the approver using the default action, but the applicant also wants to interrupt or delete the workflow.
Is there a way to achieve this using Power Automate?

I would very appreciate for any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user who started the approval process, you can go to the Power Automate portal and under Approvals find the approvals you started. Here the approvals can be cancelled. (You can also use the Approval app in Teams to keep track of your approvals).

In the workflow you will then need to cater for that outcome in the steps that follow the approval.

If that sounds too much to ask from the end user, you may want to consider NOT using the Power Automate Approval, but building the logic with SharePoint list columns that reflect approval status and outcome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!<br>
Is there a way to catch that cancellation?<br>
I want to update the SharePoint list when the workflow is canceled.

Comment: I haven't really done such a scenario, but how about you build a flow with an approval using the step that creates and waits for the approval. Then kick off the flow, start an approval, cancel it. Then see what the approval outcome comes back as in the flow. When you know that, you can then build a condition that treats that outcome.